# What power cord does a WD16001032 hard drive use?

Tags: external-hard-drive, power-supply

I have a Western Digital 160GB My Book USB external hard drive (WD16001032), but I can't find its power cord (or, at least, figure out which one it is in my box of cords).

It might be that only one power cord would fit, but I'm a bit cautious since I just tried one of the cords with a router and could smell electronics burning when I used an incorrect one.

What voltage/amps are needed for this drive? I can't find specs on Western Digital's site. I'm assuming this is due to it being an older drive.

Answer (score 1):

12 volts, 1.5 amps - http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1378